# Prove that $n^2 - 1$ is divisible by $8$

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Prove that $n^2 - 1$ is divisible by $8, for every odd integer n.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? Try $n=2$

Comment: For n=even, the statement is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean that $n^2-1$ is divisible by $8$ for all *odd* values of $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In this case, let $n=2k+1$ with $k \ge 0$. Then
$$n^2-1 = (2k+1)^2-1 = 4k^2+4k = 4k(k+1)$$
Now notice that either $k$ or $k+1$ is even to deduce divisibility by $8$.

If $n$ is even, then $n^2-1$ is odd, so is certainly *not* divisible by $8$.

Comment: "$4k^2+4k = 4k(k+1)$ 

 Now notice that either $k$ or $k+1$ is even to deduce divisibility by 8."

Could you please explain how this deduces divisibility by $8$?

Comment: Well $4$ is divisible by $4$, so if either $k$ or $k+1$ is divisible by $2$ then $4k(k+1)$ will be divisible by $4 \times 2$. More precisely, if $k=2\ell$ for some $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n^2-1=8\ell(k+1)$, and if $k+1=2\ell$ for some $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n^2-1 = 8k\ell$; in either case, $n^2-1$ is $8$ times an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Its not true for n when even . For odd n it is true as :

$(2k+1)^2 -1 = 4k^2 + 4k = 4k(k+1)$. Now $k(k+1)$ is even and hence $n^2 -1 = 4.2m = 8m $. Hence  8 divides $n^2-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Factorize $n^2-1$ into $(n-1)(n+1)$. If $n$ is even, both terms are odd. If $n$ is odd, one term is $2\pmod4$ and the other $0\pmod4$ hence it is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have that $n^2-1$ is divisible by $8$ for all $n$ !

Examples:

$n=2: n^2-1=3$

$n=4: n^2-1=15$

$n=6, 8,...$